# Does not wake up from suspend mode

Tags: release-hera, suspend, dell

I recently installed Elementary OS (5.1.7 Hera) on a Dell Latitude 5590 laptop. I have noticed that after inactivity, the machine enters sleep mode and cannot be switched on. In the syslog I see this:

```
    Nov 19 11:45:41 Latitude-5590 NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1605782741.3126] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> bound
Nov 19 11:45:41 Latitude-5590 dbus-daemon[810]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.18' (uid=0 pi
d=828 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Nov 19 11:45:41 Latitude-5590 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 19 11:45:41 Latitude-5590 dhclient[1493]: bound to 192.168.10.179 -- renewal in 228 seconds.
Nov 19 11:45:41 Latitude-5590 dbus-daemon[810]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 19 11:45:41 Latitude-5590 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 19 11:45:41 Latitude-5590 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp2s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Nov 19 11:45:41 Latitude-5590 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Nov 19 11:46:45 Latitude-5590 wpa_supplicant[839]: wlp2s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with cc:2d:e0:fb:19:ef [GTK=CCMP]
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 dhclient[1493]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.10.179 on wlp2s0 to 192.168.10.1 port 67 (xid=0x3a7c497c)
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 dhclient[1493]: DHCPACK of 192.168.10.179 from 192.168.10.1
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1605782969.3638] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   address 192.168.10.179
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1605782969.3638] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1605782969.3638] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   gateway 192.168.10.1
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1605782969.3638] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   lease time 600
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1605782969.3639] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '8.8.8.8'
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1605782969.3639] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '9.9.9.9'
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 NetworkManager[828]: <info>  [1605782969.3639] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> bound
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 dbus-daemon[810]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.18' (uid=0 pi
d=828 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 dhclient[1493]: bound to 192.168.10.179 -- renewal in 281 seconds.
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 dbus-daemon[810]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp2s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Nov 19 11:49:29 Latitude-5590 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Nov 19 11:50:39 Latitude-5590 gsd-power[1749]: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Az időkorlát elérve
Nov 19 11:50:39 Latitude-5590 gnome-session-binary[1590]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Az időkorlát elérve
Nov 19 11:50:39 Latitude-5590 gnome-session[1590]: gnome-session-binary[1590]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Az időkorlát elérve
Nov 19 11:51:45 Latitude-5590 wpa_supplicant[839]: wlp2s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with cc:2d:e0:fb:19:ef [GTK=CCMP]
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
............................................................................................................................................Nov 19 13:12:53 Latitude-5590 systemd-modules-load[491]: Inserted
module 'lp'
Nov 19 13:12:53 Latitude-5590 systemd-modules-load[491]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Nov 19 13:12:53 Latitude-5590 systemd-modules-load[491]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
```

Do you have any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The below solution has worked:
In /etc/default/grub file change this line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

To this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_idle.max_cstate=1 i915.enable_dc=0"

Then apply the settings and reboot the system:

sudo update-grub && reboot

[See the original site below.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241771/dell-latitude-7390-ubuntu-20-04-sometimes-hangs-and-reboot-after-pressing-s)